# button clicking in Chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, css, button

I made a button in Firefox and it works great, but in Chrome after clicking the button the text is not moving, therefore there is no button effect on click. I want to fix this for Chrome but still not mess up the code for Firefox.

<kbd>**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/DaMiller/Qj9uv/)**</kbd>

```
    .btn{
        background:-moz-linear-gradient(top,#64b24c 1%,#5ba045 31%,#509339 80%);
        background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top,#64b24c 1%,#5ba045 31%,#509339 80%);
        border:1px solid rgba(70,140,60,0.8);
        border-radius:3px;
        height:30px;width:80px;
        font-family:Corbel;font-weight:bold;font-size:16px;color:#FFF;
        text-shadow:rgba(3,3,3,0.8) 1px 1px 2px;
        padding-bottom:3px; /*bad*/
        padding:0px 0px 2px 0px; /*good*/
    }
    .btn:hover{cursor:pointer;}
    .btn:active{
        background:#509339; 
        padding:2px 0px 3px 1px; /*bad*/
        padding:0px 0px 0px 2px; /*good*/
}
```

The problem was that Chrome is not reacting to padding-left: 1px; I changed it to 2px and everything works fine for both Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: It looks like the only change on click should be the background - why would the text be moving? Also, can we assume that you are applying this class to a `button` element (as opposed to say, a `div`, which doesn't have an "active" state)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user agent stylesheet for Chrome has `padding: 2px 6px 3px 6px` for buttons. So, your top padding is not changing at all when you set it to 2px.

You probably want to explicitly override the padding for the unpressed button so that you get the same effect regardless of browser settings.

Comment: you are right, I need the same effect for both Firefox and Chrome. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

On my version of chrome (v26), the background does change, the text does not move.  Might I suggest that you remove the -bottom from the padding on the btn class:

```
padding:3px;
```

That way you'll see a movement and you'll be able to adjust it